I am facing problem in sending array and fetching array through payload in redux toolkit
I am stuck on this problem trying to dispatch a state update to the store.
This is my productSlice.js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const initialState = [];

export const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'product',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addpica: (state, action) => {
      state.push(action.payload);
    }
  }
})

export const { addpica } = productSlice.actions;

export default productSlice.reducer;

I have added a dispatch in singleproduct.jsx
function abfunction(product) {
  dispatch(addpica(product))
}

...

<button onClick={abfunction}>ADD TO CART</button>

The problem is I have an array with name "product" and I want to send that array as payload with dispatch. I am stuck in this problem for 2 days. I want to send and receive that "product" array.
When sending that dispatch, it's saying: "state.push is not a function".

Issue
When you pass an onClick handler as such onClick={abfunction} then the onClick event object is what is passed to the callback. The problem is that the onClick event object, named product in abfunction is passed as the action payload, and since there the event object hasn't any payload property it will be undefined.
function abfunction(product) { // onClick event object
  dispatch(addpica(product))   // click event object pass to action
}

...

<button onClick={abfunction}>ADD TO CART</button>

addpica: (state, action) => {
  state.push(action.payload); // click event has no payload property!!
}

Solution Suggestion
Update the UI code to pass the appropriate addpica payload value.
Examples:

Use an anonymous callback function to pass a product object refernece:
function abfunction(product) {
  dispatch(addpica(product));
}

...

<button onClick={() => abfunction(product)}>ADD TO CART</button>


Don't consume the click event object and pass a product object reference to action:
function abfunction() {
  dispatch(addpica(product));
}

...

<button onClick={abfunction}>ADD TO CART</button>




@RamanandGupta Here's a running sandbox demo of your code.

Wow Your Solution Worked! I deeply want to say : Thank You So Much. (Please help me fix 1 console error: TypeError: state.push is not a function)

@RamanandGupta Do you have other case reducers that update this state? Or maybe you are selecting and mutating the state reference outside Redux? See if you can create a sandbox of your own that reproduces the "state.push is not a function" issue. This may also be a good follow-on question in a new post.
